# Need specific line of string from Invoke-WebRequest output

Tags: powershell

I've got the following:

```
$WebContent = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "URLHERE/$PCNAME" -UseDefaultCredential |
              Select-Object -ExpandProperty Content
```

And it outputs perfectly:

```
Key1: sfsdfsdfsfdsfsdsfs
Key2: SD:34:SD:34:SD:34
Version: 4
Timestamp: 4/13/2018 4:00:11 PM
```

But I need to be able to put the content of Key1 and Key2 into a variable, without the space, and accommodating the possibility of varying lengths of each key.

I was trying to use `Substring($len - 83,14)` to get the length of it all and parse out the exact spot of the Key, but for some reason they are changing in length and a few have cut off the key which gives a incorrect output. I probably need to get the whole line and then put into a variable everything after the ':' and ' '.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can't you do `$WebContent.Key1`?

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 The data appears to be the response from a web request, so it's most likely a string array, not a PowerShell object.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Sometimes the `iwr` cmdlet is nice and parses things into objects for you, but it's impossible to know with certainty without more detail.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 does it? I've only known `irm` to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the response you got is text, not a structured object, you could do something like this:

```
$data = $WebContent -replace ': ', '=' |
        Out-String |
        ConvertFrom-StringData
```

The above will replace colons followed by a space with a `=` character and merge all into a single string, so that `ConvertFrom-StringData` can convert the list of key/value pairs to a hashtable. Then you can assign values to individual variables like this:

```
$key = $data['Key1']
```

or just use the hashtable as-is.

Answer (score 1):

Split the content into lines, match the ones you want and ignore the rest, replace the part you don't want, store the result:

```
$test = @'
Key1: sfsdfsdfsfdsfsdsfs
Key2: SD:34:SD:34:SD:34
Version: 4
Timestamp: 4/13/2018 4:00:11 PM
'@


$result = ($test -split "`r?`n") -match '^key.: ' -replace '^key.: '
```

Depending on what you mean by "get the two keys into one variable"; this result will be an array of string.

One of many, many possible approaches.

Comment: `$key1, $key2 = ...`?