# If Command Response Contains

Tags: powershell

I recently completed a new PowerShell script that imports a CSV into our Active Directory, it creates, disables, and enables accounts as needed. I'm now attempting to mimic this solution for G Suite, using GAM. I use the following command for AD to set a boolean that I can utilize throughout the script as needed.

```
$exist = [bool]($account=([adsisearcher]"(samaccountname=$($user.samaccountname))").findone())
```

GAM doesn't provide a simple check like this, however, I can trigger a command to respond inline with information about an account.

Is it possible to scan the response provided by a command? For example...

The Command:

```
gam whatis testuser8 nolicenses nogroups noaliases noschemas
```

Responds:

```
test...@rdschool.org is a user
User: test...@rdschool.org
First Name: Test
Last Name: User8
Is a Super Admin: False
Is Delegated Admin: False
2-step enrolled: False
2-step enforced: False
Has Agreed to Terms: False
IP Whitelisted: False
Account Suspended: True
Suspension Reason: ADMIN
Must Change Password: False
Google Unique ID: 107453623127020962025
Customer ID: C03kt1m66
Mailbox is setup: True
Included in GAL: True
Creation Time: 2018-06-11T14:57:36.000Z
Last login time: Never
Google Org Unit Path: /Test/Vault
```

How can I, using PowerShell, interpret that the response contains "Account Suspended: True", so that I can act on it?

Comment: I don't really now what objekt the command returns, but maybe this is enough: `[string](gam whatis testuser8 nolicenses nogroups noaliases noschemas) -match "Account Suspended: True"` - This should return either `$true` or `$false`.

Comment: Alternatively remove the first line and [convert](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51428072/1630171) the rest of the output to a hashtable or custom object, so that you can check the desired value(s) by key or property name.